# What are the requirements for setting up a solo 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, solo-401k

I'm leaving a job that has a 401k for a startup that has no 401k.  I can switch to using a traditional IRA but the max contribution per year is 5K, so that would cut my tax-deffered savings per year by approximately 10K.

So is it possible for me to open up a solo 401K even though I have a full time job?  Thanks

Comment: If your new company is paying you a salary (that will be reported as wages on a W-2 form), then that money cannot be used to contribute to a solo 401k. If you are a consultant and will be reporting your earnings on Schedule C, that is a different matter.

Comment: Uh, this is a great *answer* not a comment. +1 anyway.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  Thanks.  I responded in a hurry since I did not have enough time then to compose a satisfactory (to me) answer. Of course, littleadv's answer covers it all perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo 401k is a simplified 401k plan for an employer who only employs himself (spouses allowed). As Dillip said, you have to have *self-employed* income.